# Generate a range of dates with a record

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a scenario within this record:

```
ID  emp  sdate               edate              datediff
10  54  2019-11-21 01:00:00 2019-11-22 01:00:00 1
11  54  2019-11-26 01:00:00 2019-11-27 01:00:00 1
12  54  2019-11-26 01:00:00 2019-11-27 01:00:00 1
13  54  2019-12-26 01:00:00 2019-12-29 01:00:00 3
14  54  2020-01-06 01:00:00 2020-01-10 01:00:00 4
15  54  2019-12-17 01:00:00 2019-12-17 19:00:00 0
16  54  2019-12-17 01:00:00 2019-12-17 22:00:00 0
17  54  2019-12-17 01:00:00 2019-12-17 23:00:00 0
18  527 2020-01-28 14:00:00 2020-01-28 15:00:00 0
```

All datediff greater than one i need to increment the `sdate` and `edate` something like this from the `id = 13 and 14`

```
13  54  2019-12-26 01:00:00 2019-12-29 01:00:00 3
14  54  2020-01-06 01:00:00 2020-01-10 01:00:00 4
```

I need a result something like

```
13  54 2019-12-26 01:00:00  2019-12-26 01:00:00
13  54 2019-12-27 01:00:00  2019-12-27 01:00:00
13  54 2019-12-28 01:00:00  2019-12-28 01:00:00
13  54 2019-12-29 01:00:00  2019-12-29 01:00:00
14  54 2020-01-06 01:00:00  2020-01-06 01:00:00
14  54 2020-01-07 01:00:00  2020-01-07 01:00:00
14  54 2020-01-08 01:00:00  2020-01-08 01:00:00
14  54 2020-01-09 01:00:00  2020-01-09 01:00:00
14  54 2020-01-10 01:00:00  2020-01-10 01:00:00
```

Is it possible that this `13` and `14` records to make like this?

Any answers and advice are pretty much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: is id auto_increment or a primary key or a unique key or a reference for an FK? Do you have a dates/calendar table?

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon the id is primary key.. but i dont need the id anymore just the date only

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it with a recursive query (available in MySQ 8.0 only):

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, emp, sdate, sdate + interval 1 day edate, datediff from mytable
    union all
    select id, emp, sdate + interval 1 day, edate + interval 1 day, datediff - 1 
    from cte 
    where datediff - 1 > 0
)
select id, emp, sdate, edate from cte
order by id, sdate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=436f35d0517d05b112da050671d22717)**:

```
id | emp | sdate               | edate              
-: | --: | :------------------ | :------------------
10 |  54 | 2019-11-21 01:00:00 | 2019-11-22 01:00:00
11 |  54 | 2019-11-26 01:00:00 | 2019-11-27 01:00:00
12 |  54 | 2019-11-26 01:00:00 | 2019-11-27 01:00:00
13 |  54 | 2019-12-26 01:00:00 | 2019-12-27 01:00:00
13 |  54 | 2019-12-27 01:00:00 | 2019-12-28 01:00:00
13 |  54 | 2019-12-28 01:00:00 | 2019-12-29 01:00:00
14 |  54 | 2020-01-06 01:00:00 | 2020-01-07 01:00:00
14 |  54 | 2020-01-07 01:00:00 | 2020-01-08 01:00:00
14 |  54 | 2020-01-08 01:00:00 | 2020-01-09 01:00:00
14 |  54 | 2020-01-09 01:00:00 | 2020-01-10 01:00:00
15 |  54 | 2019-12-17 01:00:00 | 2019-12-18 01:00:00
16 |  54 | 2019-12-17 01:00:00 | 2019-12-18 01:00:00
17 |  54 | 2019-12-17 01:00:00 | 2019-12-18 01:00:00
18 | 527 | 2020-01-28 14:00:00 | 2020-01-29 14:00:00
```

Comment: Appreciated your answer @GMB but i am using 6.0 only.